# how to retrive the data of multiline text using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

how to i get CSOM code retrieve multi line text from sharePoint online?

i was able to get other fields relatively easily

```
                Web web = ctx.Web;
                List list = web.Lists.GetById(new Guid("fe15d182-4e65-48a9-a613-6dcfae756c69"));
                var q = new CamlQuery() { ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Manager' /><Value Type='User'>TOM</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>" };
                var r = list.GetItems(q);
                ctx.Load(r);


                string result = string.Empty;
                foreach (SPclient.ListItem itm in r)
                {
                    FieldUserValue name = itm.FieldValues["Manager"] as FieldUserValue;
                    string person = name.LookupValue;
                    //Console.WriteLine(itm.Id + "     " + itm["Manager"].ToString() + "     " + person);

                    MessageBox.Show(itm.Id + "     " + itm["Title"].ToString() + "     " + multitextValue + "    " + person);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load `FieldValuesAsText` explicitly.

Try it as below:

```
Web web = ctx.Web;
List list = web.Lists.GetById(new Guid("fe15d182-4e65-48a9-a613-6dcfae756c69"));
var q = new CamlQuery() { ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Manager' /><Value Type='User'>TOM</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>" };
var r = list.GetItems(q);
ctx.Load(r,items=>items.Include(item=>item.FieldValuesAsText));    
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (SPclient.ListItem itm in r)
{
    FieldUserValue name = itm.FieldValues["Manager"] as FieldUserValue;
    string person = name.LookupValue;

    string richTextField = Convert.ToString(itm.FieldValuesAsText[FIELD_NAME]); //internal name of field

    //Console.WriteLine(itm.Id + "     " + itm["Manager"].ToString() + "     " + person);

    MessageBox.Show(itm.Id + "     " + itm["Title"].ToString() + "     " + multitextValue + "    " + person);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gautam, I got an error on the line  string richTextField = Convert.ToString(itm.FieldValuesAsText["SubordinateEmails"]);   Error {"The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."}"

Comment: Field name SubordinateEmails is correct.

Comment: Can you check edited code ? have added `ctx.ExecuteQuery` method

Comment: the above code does not enter the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got the answer from here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5aee5632-58e9-40db-8f5c-7da751551a4c/get-the-text-value-from-multiline-text-field-in-sharepoint-using-net-com?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
var listItem = list.GetItemById(itemId);
var FieldValues = listItem.FieldValuesAsText;
clientContext.Load(FieldValues);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
string multitextfield = FieldValues["MultiLine FieldName"];
```